# Opencv Python API for FileStorage

Tags: python, opencv, file-storage

I am trying to use opencv-python API for reading yml files.

How can I read a 'yml' file that has nested elements like

'example.yml'

```
%YAML:1.0
empty:
   - { type:0, condition:0, slot:0, tr:[ 269, 120 ], tl:[ 204, 120 ] }
   - { type:0, condition:0, slot:0, tr:[ 200, 121 ], tl:[ 131, 121 ] }
   - { type:0, condition:0, slot:0, tr:[ 127, 123 ], tl:[ 56, 123 ] }
```

I tried

```
import cv2
fs = cv2.FileStorage('example.yml', cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
fn = fs.getNode('empty')
```

It works fine, but I cannot access the nested elements such as 'type', 'condition', 'slot', 'tr', and 'tl'.

Do you know the way to access them?

Comment: What version of opencv-python are you using? According to [this post on answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/55507/writing-filestream-with-python/), the Python bindings did not support FileStorage at all before 3.x, and weren't actually complete and fully functional until 3.2.

Comment: I use opencv 3.3.1 and python 2.7.